Distribution of transformed normal
Suppose $X$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function. What is the distribution of $\Phi(X)$?

What kind of answer are you looking for?  A name, a pdf, a CDF, properties, ...?

What have you tried on this problem? Would you like to share?

I just thought it was an interesting question I never saw before. I was wondering if it has a name its properties. It came up when I was thinking about using simulation to estimate the power of a hypothesis test.

A better simulation might be $\Phi\left(\dfrac{X-\bar X}{s_X}\right)$ where for a large enough sample you hope for something close to uniform: essentially this is what a qqplot (qqnorm in R) looks at.

For $0<t<1$, the distribution function is
$$P\left[\Phi(X)<t\right]
=P\left[X<\Phi^{-1}(t)\right]
=P\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{\Phi^{-1}(t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right]
=\Phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$
Now, let $\phi$ denote the standard normal density function. The density function is the derivative of the distribution function,
$$\frac{\phi\left(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(t)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\sigma\phi\left(\Phi^{-1}(t)\right)}$$

You can just run a basic simulation,
x = rnorm(1e6)
y = pnorm(x)
plot(density(y))

This is the image you would get,

This suggests that the new distribution is uniform.

That is the case when $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$, and similarly looking at the distribution of $F_X(X)$ for any continuous random variable, but not otherwise.   Try something like x = rnorm(1e6,2,1) or perhaps like x = rnorm(1e6,0.2,0.3)  or x = rnorm(1e6,0,4)  to see some other possibilities - something close to Beta distributions but perhaps not exactly them.

No need for a simulation in this special case: you just generated a million random values  merely to illustrate the Probability Integral Transform.
